# A series of &n& implications - for what values of $n$ is this proposition a tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For what values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is this proposition a tautology:
$$((p \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p$$ ($n$ implications)
 
1. I want to consider two cases: (1) $p = 1$ and (2) $p = 0$ 
(1) $1 \rightarrow 1$ is always $1$, thus this works for all $n$ 
(2.1) I check the first several steps: 
$n=1$: $p \rightarrow p $ is true 
$n=2$: $1 \rightarrow p$ is false 
$n = 3$: $0 \rightarrow p$ is true 
$n = 4$: $1 \rightarrow p$ is false 
 
Based on that, I make an assumption that this proposition is a tautology for odd numbers and it is not for even numbers. I want to use induction to show that:

1) I have already checked the case for n =1 and n =2: it holds.

2) Let's call the proposition $\psi(n)$. I assume that $\psi(2k+1), k\in \mathbb{N}$ is true and $\psi(2k+2)$ is false.

for $\psi(2k+3)$ we have $\psi(2k+2) \rightarrow0=1$ and for $\psi(2k+4)$: $1 \rightarrow0=0$

3) Therefore, the proposition is a tautology for odd values of n. 
Could you tell me if I have written this proof correctly? Apart from that, any suggestions on how to improve it would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks strange to me. You claim

> for $\psi(2k+3)$ we have $\psi(2k+2) \rightarrow0=1$ and for $\psi(2k+4)$: $1 \rightarrow0=0$

I don't see how this is true, especially the first part is really strange. The second part is just very poorly explained, but sounds true. You should write this part out, or better yet, rewrite your whole proof.

---

To improve the proof, I would write out that $\psi(n)$ is the proposition $\psi(n-1)\to p$ and start from there. The inductive statement would be inductive on $k$, not on $n$, so the inductive statement would be

> For every $k\in\mathbb N$, the statement $\psi(2k)$ is false and the statement $\psi(2k+1)$ is true.

Comment: And so  $\psi(2k+2) = \psi(2k+1) \rightarrow p$ which is false. But what about $\psi(2k+3)$ as for the next odd number? I would have to use $\psi(2k+2)$ which is not part of the assumption, is it okay?

Comment: @Aemilius It's not part of the assumption, but it is a *consequence* of the assumption, and you already proved it, so yes, it's ok.

Comment: Note: for the inductive proof just use that $\psi(2(k+1)) ~=~ ((\psi(2k)\to p)\to p) ~ = ~\psi(2k)\vee p$, and the base cases $\psi(0)=\top$ and $\psi(1)=p$.  $$\psi(k) := \begin{cases} \top &:& k=0\\ \psi(k-1)\to p &:& k\in\Bbb N^+\end{cases}$$